# Updating TextView

Tags: java, android

I can't seem to get things to display programatically using text views? I have a main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Name"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, I am a Button" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in my code, I use:

```
//Update the GUI
setContentView(R.layout.main);
TextView guiStr;
guiStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
guiStr.setText(username);
```

But the username does not display on the screen. I get just the default text in the XML. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have another TextView with the same id. Try assigning your TextView another id - username1 for example